# Is there any way in Microsoft Excel that two or more consective blank rows converted to one blank row

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have MS Excel 2007 document where i have many blank lines between data.
i want that if there are more than one blank lines then all others are deleted but only one blank line is left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is one solution that you can use to automatically eliminate blank lines.
If you need to replace multiple blank lines by one, you will probably need a macro. See this article for an example that you can adapt : [How to merge duplicate rows in Excel](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080907114740AAk0iOn).

From [Excel 2007: Eliminate Blank Rows in a Spreadsheet](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2189/excel_2007_eliminate_blank_rows/)

> Blank rows can be beneficial when it
>   comes to making your spreadsheet
>   easier to read, however if you are
>   going to pull the data into another
>   application (such as Access), the
>   blank rows can cause you some
>   problems. You could go through the
>   painful task of selecting and removing
>   these rows individually, but if you
>   are working with a large spreadsheet,
>   it could take forever to accomplish
>   this. Instead, utilize Go To Special
>   and let Excel do the work for you.
>   Here’s how:
>
> 1. Select the range of data that contains the blank rows.
> 2. Go to the Ribbon, and select the Home tab.
> 3. In the Editing section, click the small arrow next to Find & Select.
> 4. Select Go To Special.
> 5. Select the Blanks radio button and click OK.
> 6. All blank rows within the selected data range will be highlighted.
> 7. Go to the Ribbon.
> 8. Click the small arrow beneath Delete.
> 9. Select Delete Sheet Rows

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:
* create a new column (I call it A in the following)
* enter numbers 1,2,3 .. in the cells of that column. So this is basically a rownumbr
* create another column (I'll call it B)
* fill the column with a little function: returning the value of A in the same row, when the row above is not empty or the own row is not empty, and a huge number otherwise. (huge must be bigger then the number of rows you have, including all blanks)
* Now sort the complete sheet by column B. the double blank rows should be at the end of the sheet, while everything else is unchanged.
* remove the columns A + B